# How to configure shipping rates based on product attributes

Tags: commerce

I am implementing Drupal Commerce 2

My use case

Product such as an album release is offered as a product in different format such as LP, 7inch, CD. Each format has a different shipping cost. In other words, different attribute has different costs of shipping.

Music Album xxx

- attribute LP - costs $17 to ship
- attribute 7 inch costs $5 to ship
- attribute CD costs $3 to ship

How do we do this with Drupal commerce shipping?

I tried to setup with "product category" taxonomy; however, it's only applicable on the product level, not to the product attribute.

Answer (score 1):

I had to do a similar thing and ran into the same issue. I was selling prints of various sizes.

Each print was a product. Each size of the print was a variation inside of that product. Depending on the print size, I wanted to apply a certain amount for shipping.

Ultimately, you'll need to add a custom shipping condition.

**What I did**

On the Variation Type, I added a List (Text) field called `field_package_size`. Here, I put my shipping sizes (small, medium, large).

Then, I created a shipping method. But as you see, there's no condition to get the info from the variation. Just "product category" which only taps into taxonomy terms at the Product level.

**Create the Shipping Condition**

The Commerce docs have a good outline of making a condition: https://docs.drupalcommerce.org/commerce2/developer-guide/core/conditions#conditioninterface-and-conditionbase

I create a custom module that handles my conditions. All the module has besides the base `custom_module.info.yml` file is one file.

```
custom_module/src/Plugin/Commerce/Condition/PackageSizeInOrder.php
```

Here's the entire file:

```
<?php

namespace Drupal\plateau_astro_commerce\Plugin\Commerce\Condition;

use Drupal\commerce\Plugin\Commerce\Condition\ConditionBase;
use Drupal\Core\Entity\EntityInterface;
use Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface;

/**
 * Provides the SKU prefix in order condition.
 *
 * @CommerceCondition(
 *   id = "package_size_in_order",
 *   label = @Translation("Package Size"),
 *   display_label= @Translation("Package Size"),
 *   category = @Translation("Products", context = "Commerce"),
 *   entity_type = "commerce_order",
 * )
 */
class PackageSizeInOrder extends ConditionBase {

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function defaultConfiguration() {
    return [
      'package_size' => '',
      'exclude' => FALSE,
    ] + parent::defaultConfiguration();
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function buildConfigurationForm(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    $form = parent::buildConfigurationForm($form, $form_state);

    $form['package_size'] = [
      '#type' => 'textfield',
      '#title' => $this->t('Shipping format'),
      '#description' => $this->t('Enter some shipping format to use as a condition for this offer. Separate with comma'),
      '#default_value' => $this->configuration['package_size'],
      '#required' => TRUE,
    ];
    $form['exclude'] = [
      '#type' => 'checkbox',
      '#title' => $this->t('Exclusive condition'),
      '#description' => $this->t('Check this box if the condition should be exclusive. IE the condition will pass if the order contains none of the package sizes listed.'),
      '#default_value' => $this->configuration['exclude'],
    ];

    return $form;
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function submitConfigurationForm(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
    parent::submitConfigurationForm($form, $form_state);

    $values = $form_state->getValue($form['#parents']);
    $this->configuration['package_size'] = $values['package_size'];
    $this->configuration['exclude'] = $values['exclude'];
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function evaluate(EntityInterface $entity) {
    $exclude = (bool) $this->configuration['exclude'];
    $this->assertEntity($entity);
    /** @var \Drupal\commerce_order\Entity\OrderInterface $order */
    $order = $entity;
    
    /** @var \Drupal\commerce_product\Entity\ProductVariationInterface $purchased_entity */
    $items = $order->getItems();
    
    $formats = preg_split('/\r\n|\r|\n/', $this->configuration['package_size']);
    
    foreach ($items as $item) {
      if (!$purchased_entity = $item->getPurchasedEntity()) {
        continue;
      }
      if (!$purchased_entity || $purchased_entity->getEntityTypeId() !== 'commerce_product_variation') {
        continue;
      }
      if (!method_exists($purchased_entity, 'getSku')) {
        // Not sure what to do then.
        continue;
      }
      
      $size = $purchased_entity->get('field_package_size')->getString();
      
      foreach ($formats as $format) {
        if (empty($format)) {
          continue;
        }
        $config = explode(',', (string) $format);
        foreach ($config as $config_format) {
          $config_format = trim($config_format);
          if (empty($config_format)) {
            continue;
          }
          if (strpos($size, $config_format) === 0) {
            return !$exclude;
          }
        }
      }
    }
    return $exclude;
  }

}
```

I'll go through each of the functions.

**`defaultConfiguration()`**

Sets the defaults when loading the condition form.

**`buildConfigurationForm()`**

Builds the form. For me, all I really needed was a simple field that I could type the name of the value small, medium, or large.

Initially, I had a taxonomy term on my product variation. Ideally this field would be a dropdown of those terms, but loading in taxonomy terms was beyond my skill (it can be done! I just didn't know how to do it).

This is why I instead used a text field on my Product Variation.

**`submitConfigurationForm()`**

Submits the form.

**`evaluate()`**

This checks to see the value on `field_package_size`. If you follow my setup, you shouldn't need to adjust anything here except what the name of your field is on your Product Variation.

**Create Shipping Method for Each Shipping Cost**

After you create the file above, clear the cache, a new shipping condition should appear.

Then, you create a Shipping Method for each one you have. For mine, I have Small, Medium, and Large.

On each method, I add this custom condition, then fill in the value from `field_package_size`. Example below for my Small shipping method.

[image: Small Condition]

**Combine products into one shipment**

For my scenario, if somebody bought a product with a variation tagged with 'Small' and 'Medium', then I'd put both products into the same package/shipment with the 'Medium' price.

You will have to do some condition logic in the Shipping Method. I'll put screenshots of my Small, Medium, and Large shipping conditions in case you run into this snag:

Small

[image: Small Condition]

Medium

[image: Medium Condition]

Large

[image: Large Condition]

Answer (score 0):

mmmm if you need it bad you will need to make your own custom price resolver
what i did was put a price field on the attribute itself then did ...

```
public function resolve(PurchasableEntityInterface $entity, $quantity, Context $context) {     
if ($entity->get('type')->getValue()[0]['target_id'] == 'something') {
    $base = (float) $entity->price->number;
    $code = $entity->price->currency_code;

    $wrap = $entity->attribute_attrib_name->referencedEntities()[0];
    $wrap_pice = (float) $wrap->field_price->getValue()[0]['number'];
    $new_price = $base + $wrap_pice;
    return new Price($new_price, $code);
}
```

see https://docs.drupalcommerce.org/commerce2/developer-guide/pricing/price-resolvers
for more info

Comment: To do this, does it mean I need to create a custom module?

Comment: yep you do but its not hard to do prob take you 5-10 min of reading 
https://www.drupal.org/docs/creating-custom-modules/step-by-step-tutorial-hello-world/tutorial-introduction